# MS Access list class objects in a form (like controls collection)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form where i dynamically instanciate objects from a custom class module.
The resulting objects are defined public and i can access then in a module via `Forms("Formname").objName1.Property`

I want to access the objects dynamically too, like it would be possible in the controls collection: `Forms("Formname").Controls("objName" & ID).Property`
but there is no collection of objects.

Has someone an advice?

Comment: Define your own public collection in the form module, and add the objects to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a publicly accessible collection for this, e.g.

```vb
Dim myObjects As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set MyObjects = New Collection
    MyObjects.Add Obj1, "First Object"
    MyObjects.Add Obj2, "Second Object"
End Sub
```

Then, in the global scope:

```vb
Forms("MyForm").MyObjects("First Object").Property
```

Of course, if you really wanted to do fancy things, you could use a [custom collection class](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/CollectionClass.aspx), which would allow you to have more control over the class and have intellisense on its members.

Comment: PERFECT! Eric this is exactly what i needed.